# FATAL EXCEPTION: main Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: java

I have this error when I click on row users the emulator stops

```
if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myUid) && chat.getSender().equals(hisUid) ||
                            chat.getReceiver().equals(hisUid) && chat.getSender().equals(myUid)) {
                        chatList.add(chat);
                    }
```

I tried to change myUid with firebase.getUid it didn't work

```
if (chat.getReceiver().equals(firebaseAuth.getUid()) && chat.getSender().equals(hisUid) ||
                            chat.getReceiver().equals(hisUid) && chat.getSender().equals(firebaseAuth.getUid())) {
                        chatList.add(chat);
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the object chat comes as null like this:

```
if (chat != null){
if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myUid) && chat.getSender().equals(hisUid) ||
                        chat.getReceiver().equals(hisUid) && chat.getSender().equals(myUid)) {
                    chatList.add(chat);
                }}
```